# Getting jquery element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do a simple conditional statement based on the value of a `<select>` element using jQuery. This works fine:

```
var WantCategory = document.getElementById('WantCategory').value
if ((WantCategory <= 0) || (WantCategory >= 4)) {
    alert('hi')
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
var WantCategory =$('select.WantCategory').val()
if ((WantCategory <= 0) || (WantCategory >= 4)) {
    alert('hi')
}
```

Here is the html portion

```
<label for="WantCategory">Item Category
    <select id="WantCategory">
        <optgroup label="Group of Options">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: You select by class rather then by ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var WantCategory = $('select#WantCategory').val();
if ((WantCategory <= 0) || (WantCategory >= 4)) {
    alert('hi')
}
```

Your original code was selecting by class rather than by id.

Answer (score 1):

var val = $(#WantCategory).val()
ID must be unique, so you don't need tag name

Answer (score 1):

If the id on the select is unique (which ideally it should be) then you should be able to just do:

```
var WantCategory = $('#WantCategory').val();
```

Comment: Not "ideally", it **must** be unique per the [W3C HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id). :-)